ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwn' even though I installed pwntools with pipx, and already set PYTHONPATH
I'm working on arch linux.
I need the python module 'pwntools'.
First I did this:
pipx install pwntools
Then a warning:
Note: '/home/woc/.local/bin' is not on your PATH environment variable. These apps will not be globally accessible until your PATH is updated. Run pipx ensurepath to automatically add it, or manually modify your PATH in your shell's config file (e.g. ~/.bashrc). 
What I tried:
Then I add ~/.local/bin to both my PATH and PYTHONPATH. And I checked it, seeming no problem.
 print (sys.path)
 ['', '/home/woc/.local/bin', '/usr/lib/python312.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.12', '/usr/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages']
And there are many modules in ~/.local/bin, including one named 'pwn'
What I expected:
import the modules in ~/.local/bin
However, when I import pwn (a module in that directory) in python code, I was told ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwn'
Why???

Modules do not belong in ~/local/bin.  That's for command-line binaries.  Are you sure that .py files were installed there?

Oh, I just find these files don't end with  .py  . After I add suffix to filename,  the original error disappear. Thank you Very much! But I wonder why these file name become like this...

The files in ~/.local/bin are intended to be called as standalone commands, like "pwn".  The modules must be elsewhere.

The whole point of pipx is to install Python applications (not libraries) such that their dependencies are isolated from the rest of the system:

pipx is made specifically for application installation, as it adds isolation yet still makes the apps available in your shell: pipx creates an isolated environment for each application and its associated packages.

By design, such applications will not be importable from other Python environments. If you want to install libraries into an existing environment, use pip, Poetry, Hatch, or any number of other tools.
